# creating a node with different labels in py2neo ogm

Tags: python, python-3.x, neo4j, py2neo

I was asking myself if it is possible to create a node with different labels with the ogm in py2neo.

cypher:

```
CREATE(n:label1:label2{name:'testname'})
RETURN n
```

py2neo ogm:

```
class label(GraphObject):
    __primarykey__ = "name"

    name=Property()

templabel=label()
templabel.name='testname'
graph.push(templabel)
#graph got initialized with graph=graph()
```

As you can see, the classname is defined as the labelname: [py2neo ogm doc](http://py2neo.org/v3/ogm.html)

Kind regards,
resc